# Paypal service is not starting (sandbox account), am getting below error

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox, android-multidex

I have an activity named sample activity.From that activity i opened an intent,
that was navigationlayout1 activity, which had a paypal service. Oncreate this service should be added like they(paypal) done in their example.
I have not had this problem before when i was using no multidex option.

I got an error like "exit value 2", my gradle couldn't completed due to this error. I have done some research on it to clear this error off.

Finally my previous error(exit value 2) got cleared. I was happy because now there is no error. But unexpectedly i got this error. I have been stucked with error for the past 3 days. I have been researching all the time. This is the right time to ask over here without wasting my time any more ..Please help me

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3.internal.tls.OkHostnameVerifier
                                                       at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:364)
                                                       at com.paypal.android.sdk.cc.a(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.paypal.android.sdk.cm.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService.a(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2656)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NavigationLayout1.class);

   startActivity(intent);
```

this page will be opened

NavigationLayout1.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.example.administrator.login.R;
import com.example.administrator.login.helper.ImageLoader;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalConfiguration;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService;
//import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;


public class NavigationLayout1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    // private static final String TAG = "paymentdemoblog";
    /**
     * - Set to PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION to move real money.
     *
     * - Set to PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX to use your test credentials
     * from https://developer.paypal.com
     *
     * - Set to PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK to kick the tires
     * without communicating to PayPal's servers.
     */
    // private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT =
    // PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK;
    private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;

    // note that these credentials will differ between live & sandbox
    // environments.
    private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "Af3H9MCGkS0bGBEdj_KFIeZU6uip0RK0hLEONpOxo73KYpboXEsAiib6kwUXfM2n-W3wr9b2bQ_JRKhB";

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT = 2;

    private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
            .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
            .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
                    // The following are only used in PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.
            .merchantName("Hipster Store")
            .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(
                    Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy"))
            .merchantUserAgreementUri(
                    Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));

    PayPalPayment thingToBuy;

    /****************************************************************Paypal*********************************/



    private String data;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_layout1);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        data=this.getIntent().getStringExtra("total");

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
        startService(intent);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {

        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
        return true;
    }

}
```

But i am getting the above error.Please help me